# Salt water and electricity

Tags: electromagnetism, electricity, electric-circuits, electrons, electric-fields

It's well known that if you place 2 electrodes connected to a battery in salt water, Positive ions will get attracted to the negative electrode, and negative ions to the positive electrode.

But what if in respect to salt water's potential both electrodes are at a (let's say 9008V and 9000V potential.) won't the positive ions get repelled by both electrodes and the negative ions attracted to both electrodes ?

EDIT #1 : The first awnser said that only potential difference matters but wouldn't positive charges going into positive charges get repelled (coulomb's law)

You may say it's because the other one has even more positive charges, but then this will mean it get's repelled to the other positive electrode and dosen't mean attracted to lower potential electrode. And why wouldn't a positive ion just get repelled by both (coloumb's law) and stay in a corner of the container.

Comment: I think you might be confused about what a voltage is. Volts do not inherently mean a positive charge. The voltage would be across both electrodes, each electrode would not have its own voltage.

Comment: Each electrode will have it's own potential relative to salt water

Answer (score 2):

Remember that in the case of potential, only the potential DIFFERENCE has any true physical meaning.  You can set the zero potential to be anywhere and all other potentials will be in reference to that point.  In other words, the zero potential is arbitrary.

Assigning an arbitrary 9000V to your lowest potential will not stop negative ions drifting to the positive $\Delta V$ and vice versa for positive ions.

Comment: i'am confused about something why dosen't the individual charges of the ions matter here ? like if they are positive they would like to go away from the other positive terminal because like charges repel. I used to know this but now i feel like i am forgetting something important .

Comment: Positive charges go in the direction of potential drop.  Why do you think 9008-9000 potential drop would push a charge less than 8-0 potential drop.  A current in an electric circuit travels in the direction of decreasing potential.  If you assign a point in the circuit as zero potential, every point upstream from that point is at positive potential.  The current still flows between those positive potential points in the direction of decreasing potential.

Comment: I think i got it. Positive ions will get repelled by positive charges in both electrodes .This will get some positive ions stuck in the corners of the container of salt water until the positive ions on the corner balance out the electric field and they are forced to go into more positive ions.

Comment: I think you are confusing positive potential with positive charge.  Just because the potential is positive at a point in a circuit, that does not mean there are positive charges there to repel anything.

Comment: Ok i am going to make an other question to clarify

Comment: ok so i think i am starting to see clear can you confirm my thought,Let's chosse ground to be arbitrarily at 0V. If the salt water is already at 100v relative to ground, and i place in it a 100v Electrode nothing will happen because the electric field created by the molecules of the salt water is equal to the electric field of the electrode so a positive charge would feel no force (in a perticular direction) because all the repulsion cancel each other is this true , (i am trying to understand this microscopically , Thanks for your time and effort.

Comment: "Electric field created by the molecules of the salt water" is not right way to look at it.  The electric field is created by the $\Delta V$ of the electrodes.  If you have 100V on each electrode, then yes, your field will be zero and the ions will not move.  Maybe it will be clearer if you look at gravitational potential which is the same principle as electric potential.  If we zero the potential on the surface , the potential energy of a mass $m$ is $mgh$ with potential is $gh$.  Everywhere above the surface the potential increases above zero, but a mass falls between two positive points.

Comment: First Thanks for your time,But The question is not why But how only potential difference matters, Look if you have two identical objects one called A and the other B . Both charged  100V and 50V in respect to ground (imagine them like two parrallel capacitors plate), and you place them on a table at like 1cm away from each other and they are unable to move. You may think that if you placed a positive test charge at the 100V that will get attracted towards the 50V. But in my opinion ground and the rest of things is at 0V so it would get repelled by both electrodes.

Comment: And now if we go back to our salt water example. If Electrode A = 108V , Electrode B = 100V , Salt water = 100V (all relative to ground) Then A positive test charge at electrode A wouldn't feel any more attraction to electrode b than it feels to the salt water.But salt water will get more and more positive due to negative ions evaporate  at the positive electrode and this will in turn raise the potential of salt water (how much depends on the capacitance of salt water because V = Q / C) and now because salt water has a higher potential , of let's say  101V The electrode B can now be called the

Comment: Negative electrode because it has negative potential relative to everything in our example (well except ground but you got what i mean ground was used only to simplify examples i didn't want to use the word potential difference everytime)

Comment: Electrode A 108V, B 100V, salt water potential will vary along the path from A to B from 108V to 100V.  You cannot set it to be 100V constant. Potential must be continuous across a boundary.

Comment: You are still incorrectly thinking that a positive potential electrode has a positive charge there.  It does not.  You really need more of a course on this than I can give.

Comment: Well thanks for trying i am gonna reread the chaptre on electric fields.